# IBOutlets changing positions while copied and pasted from another view iPhone

Tags: iphone, positioning, iboutlet

I am copying and pasting some IBOutlets from one view to another scrollview.
But they all get centered while doing the same
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to copy the container instead of the content.

Comment: Container? Can you please specify?

Comment: in IB I guess you'll have some UIButtons and UITextfield, don't you? They should be inside a UIView or UIScrollView or something. Try to copy/paste the parent view, and not the single IBOutlet. The copied content should stay in place according to parent view.